# Date Format Order in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, time-series, strftime

i have the below problem

I have this data from a csv: format: DD-MM-YYYY

[image]

But, i need the following format: MM/DD/YYYY

So, i made this code in a for loop:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_sii.at[idx,'Fecha Docto.']).strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

and give me the below result:

[image]

how i can solve this? Because the correct date may be :

```
12/10/2019
12/17/2019
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df_sii['Fecha Docto'], format='%d-%m-%Y')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df_sii['Fecha Docto.'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sii['Fecha Docto.'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df_sii['Fecha Docto.'] = df_sii['Fecha Docto.'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: give me the next error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'